# Are Java FileChannel locks closed when the corresponding Stream is closed or do I have to explicitly close them?

Tags: java, scala, file-io, locking

Eg, my code looks currently something like the following. Do I need to explicitly call `lock.release` or is it automatically released when the `FileOutputStream` is closed?

```
var os:FileOutputStream = null
var writer:PrintWriter = null
try {
  os = new FileOutputStream(name, false)
  val lock = os.getChannel().tryLock
  if(lock != null) {
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new
      OutputStreamWriter(os)))
    (write stuff to file)
  } else {
    (error stuff)
  }
} finally {
  if(writer != null) writer.close
  os.close
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the javadoc for [FileLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html):

> *"A file-lock object is initially valid. It remains valid until the lock is released by invoking the release method, by closing the channel that was used to acquire it, or by the termination of the Java virtual machine, whichever comes first."*

... and I assume that closing the stream closes the underlying channel.

Answer (score 4):

Imagined it would be released, but curious as I was I checked it with this in the finally block:

```
println("Lock: " + lock.isValid)
if (writer != null) writer.close
println("Lock: " + lock.isValid)
os.close
println("Lock: " + lock.isValid)
```

And this was the result:

```
Lock: true
Lock: false
Lock: false
```

Seems it get cleaned when you close the writer.

Answer (score 0):

This question came up when I googled with the same doubt.

Not finding an absolute answer, I did some testing testing.

I can confirm that yes, simply closing the writer will release the locks.  You do not even need to manually close the stream that is under the writer.

How I tested:

1) I run the code in Eclipse in *debug* mode.
2) After writing and flushing to the file (before closing) I attempted to delete the file using Windows Explorer.  As expected it failed due to the lock.
3) Once I stepped through the writer.close() method, but before completing the run I attempted again to delete the file.  It deleted it without a problem.

This clearly tells me that the close() method will cause the locks to be released.

NOTE:  The above is only for the JDK's File class.  Libraries that extend java.io.File might behave differently.  For example if you use an iSeries IfsJavaFile you will have a connection memory leak unless you also release an iSeries-specific server connection object.